# i used recylerview now i want when any item of recylerview is clicked then a fragment popup on full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**i still have stuck here and i need help i want to know when i clicked on recyclerview item then new fragment popup on full screen and i'm using latest version of android studio and also tell me how can i fast my android app on different devices.**

```
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    public class Listadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Listadapter.ListViewHolder>{

        String[] CourseTitle={"English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section",
                "English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section",
                "English - Lilly section",
                "English - Lilly section"};

        String[] Section={"Section (A)",
                "Section (A)","Section (A)", "Section (A)",
                "Section (A)","Section (A)","Section (A)","Section (A)"};

        String[] Coursedec={"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
                "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum"};

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myrecylce_data,parent,false);
            return new ListViewHolder(view);


        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.txt1.setText(CourseTitle[position]);
            holder.txt2.setText(Section[position]);
            holder.txt3.setText(Coursedec[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return CourseTitle.length;
        }

        public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            TextView txt1,txt2,txt3;
            public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                txt1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_onetxt);
                txt2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_twotxt);
                txt3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dsc_course);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        }
    }
```

nothing happened and i don't know how i do this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to perform some action when your recycler view item is clicked. 
For that get a reference to your recyclerview_data layouts root element. 
Do as this:

```
public class Listadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Listadapter.ListViewHolder>{

    String[] CourseTitle={"English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section",
            "English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section", "English - Lilly section",
            "English - Lilly section",
            "English - Lilly section"};

    String[] Section={"Section (A)",
            "Section (A)","Section (A)", "Section (A)",
            "Section (A)","Section (A)","Section (A)","Section (A)"};

    String[] Coursedec={"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum",
            "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of using Lorem Ipsum"};

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myrecylce_data,parent,false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txt1.setText(CourseTitle[position]);
        holder.txt2.setText(Section[position]);
        holder.txt3.setText(Coursedec[position]);

       holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Perform your action here. In your case write code to pop your 
              fragment
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return CourseTitle.length;
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView txt1,txt2,txt3;
        LinearLayout root; //Assuming your root tag is linear layout.
        public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_onetxt);
            txt2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_twotxt);
            txt3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dsc_course);
             root=itemview.findViewById(R.id.root);
        }

    }
}
```

On a side note, it would be better to use an interface callback to pop your fragment from your parent activity.
Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for help instead of fragment i'm used activity and its work :D

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it solved your issue